# How to find out number of positive eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A$ is a $3 \times 3$ symmetric matrix such that $$[x,y,1]A\left[\begin{array}{c}
 x   \\
 y   \\
 1
\end{array}\right]=xy-1.$$
Let $p$ be the number of positive eigenvalues of $A$ and let $q = rank (A) - p$. Then

(1) $p=1.$

2) $p=2.$

(3) $q=2.$

(4) $q=1.$

Since it is symmetric matrix the matrix is diagonalizable. Hence rank of A is 3.

Comment: By simplifying given equation we get, $2a_{12}(x+y)+a_{33}=xy-1$, by taking remaining all coefficients to zero.  Hence matrix is of the form $\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
 0&a_{12}&0 \\
 a_{12}&0&0  \\
 0&0&1
\end{array}\right] $ Hence eigenvalue of this matrix are $-1, a_{12}$ and $-a_{12}$, where $a_{12} $ is positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & \frac12 & 0 \\ \frac12 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Clearly $-1$ is an eigenvalue. The other eigenvalues satisfiesy $\lambda_1+\lambda_2=0$ and $\lambda_1\lambda_2=-\frac14$.  Hence the remaining eigenvalues are $\frac12$ and $-\frac12$.

$p=1$ and $q=3-1=2$.

Answer (score 0):

I wish to flesh out my colleague Siong Thye Goh's presentation of the matrix $A$.  How do we determine its entries $a_{ij}$?

We compute the entries of $A$ as follows:

$x = y = 0 \Longrightarrow a_{33} = -1; \tag 1$

$x = 1, y = 0 \Longrightarrow a_{11} + a_{13} +  a_{31} + a_{33} = -1 \Longrightarrow a_{11} + 2a_{13} = 0; \tag 2$

$x = 0, y = 1 \Longrightarrow a_{22} + a_{23} + a_{32} + a_{33} = -1 \Longrightarrow a_{22} + 2a_{23} = 0; \tag 3$

$x = y = 1 \Longrightarrow a_{11} + 2a_{12} + 2a_{13} + a_{22} + 2a_{23} + a_{33}  = 0$
$\Longrightarrow a_{11} + 2a_{12} + 2a_{13} + a_{22} + 2a_{23} = 1; \tag 4$

scrutiny of (4) in light of (3) reveals that

$a_{11} + 2a_{12} + 2a_{13} = 1, \tag 5$

and from (2),

$2a_{12} = 1, \tag 6$

whence

$a_{12} = \dfrac{1}{2}, \tag 7$

and now the symmetry of $A$ gives

$a_{21} = a_{12} = \dfrac{1}{2} \tag 8$

as well.  Substituting these values into $A$ yields

$[x, y, 1] A \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = [x, y, 1] \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & \dfrac{1}{2} & a_{13} \\ \dfrac{1}{2} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\ a_{31} & a_{32} & -1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = [x, y, 1] \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} x + \dfrac{1}{2} y + a_{13} \\ \dfrac{1}{2} x + a_{22} y + a_{23} \\ a_{31} x + a_{32} y - 1 \end{bmatrix}$
$= a_{11} x^2 + \dfrac{1}{2} xy + a_{13} x + \dfrac{1}{2} xy + a_{22} y^2 + a_{23} y +  a_{31} x + a_{32} y - 1; \tag 9$

thus,

$a_{11} x^2 + xy + a_{13} x + a_{22} y^2 + a_{23} y +  a_{31} x + a_{32} y - 1 = xy - 1, \tag{10}$

or

$a_{11} x^2 + xy + a_{13} x + a_{22} y^2 + a_{23} y +  a_{31} x + a_{32} y = xy; \tag{11}$

comparing coefficients reveals that

$a_{11} = a_{13} = a_{22} = a_{23} = a_{31} = a_{32} = 0; \tag{12}$

thus the matrix

$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \dfrac{1}{2} & 0 \\ \dfrac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}; \tag{13}$

it is now clear that $-1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with eigenvector $(0, 0, 1)^T$; the symmetry of $A$ now implies that the remaining eigenvectors may be taken orthogonal to $(0, 0, 1)^T$; thus they lie in the subspace spanned by $(1, 0, 0)^T$ and $(0, 1, 0)^T$, which is invariant under $A$, and the action of $A$ on this subspace is given by  the $2 \times 2$ matrix in the upper left corner of $A$, that is, under the action of

$B = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \dfrac{1}{2} \\ \dfrac{1}{2} & 0 \end{bmatrix}; \tag{14}$

thus the remaining eigenvalues of $A$ are those of $B$, the characteristic polynomial of which is

$\det \begin{bmatrix} -\mu & \dfrac{1}{2} \\ \dfrac{1}{2} & -\mu \end{bmatrix} = \mu^2 - \dfrac{1}{4};  \tag{15}$

the roots of the quadratic equation

$\mu^2 - \dfrac{1}{4} = 0 \tag{16}$

are

$\mu = \pm \dfrac{1}{2}; \tag{17}$

one is positive and one is negative; thus $A$ has $2$ negative eigenvalues, so

$p = 1, \tag{18}$

and thus

$q = 2. \tag{19}$